# Problems copying base64 string from xml file into text file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, base64, marshalling

I have an xml file with a tag that contains a base64 string, like this :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <PercezioniEStorni>
           <MsgPercezioniStorni>  
               <ApplicazioneChiamante>PEI</ApplicazioneChiamante> 
               <DataElaborazione>31/03/2016</DataElaborazione> 
               <CodiceSede>3700203</CodiceSede> 
               <Esercizio>2015</Esercizio>
               <Trimestre>4</Trimestre>
               <PeriodoDal>01/10/2015</PeriodoDal>
               <PeriodoAl>31/12/2015</PeriodoAl>
               <DataValidazione>31/03/2016</DataValidazione>             
               <UtenteValidatore>giuseppe</UtenteValidatore>
               <CodFiscFirmatario>VGRGPP79E08E919T</CodFiscFirmatario>  
               <PercezioniEStorniTypeZip>          
                   <!-- Base64 example String -->
                   VUVzREJCUUFDQUFJQUNOcWYwZ0FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFaQUFBQWNtVm5hWE4wY204dE1Ua3lMVEl3TVRZeE1TMHhMbmh0Yk96ZGE1UGt4blh1KzYrUzRUZDh4   V0YzOWQzQm80aFZCVlFqdTNBWkpnRHlWTDFqeUF5WkVUS3BFR2w3Ny9QcFQ2Sm1lTEZrdTFkM3I4UWdoWC9FRG0xcWhxWmt6eTlYTCtTVEsvUExuMzc4OWkvZi9mQWYvMX    rOEIvZi9mbkh2M3puL3MrLy9mbUhuLzc1NHkvL1AvLzByei8vL0pkLy91S0xuLzc0cjkvOTI3Yy92WXUvTy8zV3V4Ly8rcWN2cHIvNDRydVAvM05mL05QSC84bi84OU8vL1BvLzlaLy8rWi92L3ZQcS9=
               </PercezioniEStorniTypeZip>
           </MsgPercezioniStorni>
       </PercezioniEStorni>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The Base64 string encode a zip file (is just an example, doesn't really contains a zip file, the real string is too much long). 
I have created this xml through JAXB generated classes in this way:

```
    FileInputStream zipFis = new FileInputStream(fileZip);
    buffer = new byte[(new Long(fileZip.length())).intValue()];
    zipFis.read(buffer);
    zipFis.close();
    String encoded = Base64.encode(buffer);

    PercezioniEStorni percezioniStorni = new PercezioniEStorni();
    /** ...set other properties... **/
    MsgPercezioniStorni msgPercezioniStorni = new MsgPercezioniStorni();
    /** ...set other properties... **/
    msgPercezioniStorni.setPercezioniEStorniTypeZip(encoded.getBytes());
    percezioniStorni.setMsgPercezioniStorni(msgPercezioniStorni);

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PercezioniEStorni.class,percezioniStorni);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    marshaller.marshal(element, document);
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
    message.getSOAPBody().addDocument(document);

    File fileXml = new File(xmlPath);
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(fileXml);
    message.writeTo(fileOutput);
    fileOutput.close();
```

And then I reversed the process:

```
    File file = new File(xmlPath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
    String xml = "";
    while(br.ready()){
        xml += br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();

    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();

    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setByteStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(is);
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

    soapPart.setContent(domSource);
    message.saveChanges();
    PercezioniEStorni perc = SOAPUtil.unmarshal(PercezioniEStorni.class,message);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(new String(perc.getMsgPercezioniStorni().getPercezioniEStorniTypeZip()));
    File zipFile = new File(zipPath);
    zipFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    out.write(decoded);
    out.close();
```

Everything is working fine. The archive is successful decoded and I can unzip it.

Later i have manually copied the Base64 string from within the xml file into another text file.
I read this file from java in this way:

```
    File txtFile = new File(textFilePath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(txtFile);
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int buffer = 0;
    while ((buffer= r.read())!=-1) {
        sb.append((char)buffer);
    }
    fis.close();
    File zipFile = new File(zipPath);
    zipFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
    Base64.decode(sb.toString(),out);
    out.close();
```

This time the zip archive is corrupted. Also the size is different. 
Why? Is there any way to read the same Base64 string from another file?

Comment: Try to keep the line endings of the base 64 encoded block, rather than removing them (by using readLine) .

Comment: "The Base64 string encode a zip file" you have a text encoding (XML) of a text encoding (Base64) of data? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @Raedwald I try to explain better, the string inside the tag "<PercezioniEStorniTypeZip>" is the base64 encoding of zip file.

Comment: @Raedwald It's not a bad idea, it works perfectly while i write/read the string in the xml file. If you have any suggestions to improve this process, you're welcome :)

Comment: @Berger Base64 file is a single-line file. Anyway use BufferedReader.readLine() method is wrong, I edited the question. But unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've overlooked something: you are manually encoding some data read from a zip file:

```
String encoded = Base64.encode(buffer);
```

Then you set a property which is defined to store a byte array in Base64 to avoid anything breaking the XML rules:

```
msgPercezioniStorni.setPercezioniEStorniTypeZip(encoded.getBytes());
```

Now the bytes of the encoded string `encoded` are encoded again.

No wonder the characters from the XML cannot be made into a valid zip by a single decoding step. (Try two.)

Much better: Drop the first encoding step.

Comment: You're right! In the schema file the type of that element is `type="xsd:base64Binary"` which means that the string is encoded twice, one by me manually and one by setter of the stubbed class.
Thank you